# How to Handle Trigger-Driven Cross-Database Record Transfer with Nonexistent Users in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, permissions, cross-database

I have a situation where I have a table in a SQL Server database, and this table has a trigger that, upon a user deleting a record, transfers that record to another database on the same server. However, I'm facing an issue where if the user doesn't exist on the target database, it results in an access error.

I'd like to find a solution that doesn't involve creating user accounts for each user on the target database since the number of users is quite extensive.

Is there a way to handle this scenario gracefully without encountering access errors when transferring records between databases in SQL Server?

Comment: You could create the change record on the DB in a staging table, then have an SSIS /SQL job transfer from that table to the other DB on a schedule.

Comment: Ideally, don't have a cross-database solution. If the objects were both in the same database, then you could make use of permission chaining. Alternatively, why not use a temporal table, if you need historical versions of the data?

Comment: I think that using module signing would be a viable alternative to needing to enable cross-database permission chaining. There's a small overhead of needing to re-sign the trigger whenever it's altered but since you've already got the trigger in source control (right?), you can add the `add signature` statement alongside the trigger definition.

Comment: I'm not using "tmp" (temporary) because I want the data to persist even after the session is closed. If you store data in a temporary table or database, it will typically be cleared automatically when the session ends. If you want the data to be available across sessions, it's better to use a regular table or a more persistent storage method.@thoma a

Comment: You mentioned "Ownership Chaining." Ownership chaining is a security feature in SQL Server that allows objects within the same database to access each other's data without explicitly granting permissions. However, this feature doesn't extend to objects in different databases. So, if you need data to be accessible across databases, you might need to consider other methods like cross-database queries, linked servers, or replication, depending on your specific use case.

If you have more specific questions or need further assistance, please feel free to ask.